# Why the Generetemap is not showing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, graphics2d

I am trying to make a brick breaker game and I've already done the background but need to add bricks so map on the top. I wrote the code but the map is not showing. Do you have any ideas why? Thanks for any help

```
.......................
.......................
.......................
..............................
...............................
................................
..................................
```

```
package sample;

import java.awt.*;

public class MapGenerator
{
    public int map[][];
    public int brickWidth;
    public int brickHeight;
    public MapGenerator(int row, int col)
    {
        map = new int[row][col];
        for( int i = 0; i<map.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<map[0].length;j++)
            {
                map[i][j] =  1;
            }
        }

        brickWidth = 540/col;
        brickWidth =150/row;

    }
    public void draw(Graphics2D g)
    {
        for( int i = 0; i<map.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++)
            {
                if (map[i][j] > 0)
                {
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                    g.fillRect(j * brickWidth + 80, i*brickHeight +50, brickWidth,brickHeight);


                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

```
package sample;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class gameplay extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener
{
    private boolean play = false;
    private int score = 0;
    private int totalBricks = 21;

    private Timer timer;
    private int delay = 8;

    private int playerX =310;

    private int ballposX = 500;
    private int ballposY = 350;
    private int ballXdir = -1;
    private int ballYdir = -2;

    private MapGenerator map;

    public gameplay()
    {
        map = new MapGenerator(3,7);

        addKeyListener(this );
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        timer = new Timer(delay, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        //backgroung

        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillRect(1,1,692,692);

        //drawing map

        map.draw((Graphics2D)g);

        //border
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillRect(0,0,5,592);
        g.fillRect(0,0,692,3);
        g.fillRect(691,0,3,592);

        //paddle

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(playerX,550,100,8);

        //ball
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillOval(ballposX,ballposY,20,20);

        g.dispose();
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        timer.start();

        if(play)
        {
            if(new Rectangle(ballposX, ballposY, 20, 20).intersects(new Rectangle(playerX,550,100,8)))
            {
                ballYdir =-ballYdir;
            }
            ballposX += ballXdir;
            ballposY += ballYdir;
            if(ballposX < 0 )
            {
                ballXdir = -ballXdir;
            }
            if (ballposY < 0)
            {
                ballYdir = -ballYdir;
            }
            if(ballposX > 670)
            {
                ballXdir = -ballXdir;
            }
        }

        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            if(playerX >= 600)
            {
                playerX = 600;
            }
            else
            {
                moveRight();
            }
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {
            if(playerX < 10)
            {
                playerX = 10;
            }
            else
            {
                moveLeft();
            }
        }
    }
    public void moveRight()
    {
        play = true;
        playerX+=20;
    }

    public void moveLeft()
    {
        play = true;
        playerX-=20;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }
}
```

```
package sample;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame obj = new JFrame();
        gameplay Gameplay = new gameplay();
        obj.setBounds(10,10,700,600);
        obj.setTitle("Breakout Ball");
        obj.setResizable(false);

        obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        obj.add(Gameplay);
        obj.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if you wrote code but it doesn't do what you expected it to do, you narrow down the problem by a process called "debugging". Basically, you try simple things first: Can you draw a Rectangle at a hardcoded position in front of your background? If yes, fine, try something more complicated. If no, you've narrowed down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your bricks have no height. One of the below needs to be 'brickHeight' in your code.

```
  brickWidth = 540/col;
  brickWidth =150/row;
```